# FFmpeg timestamps

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, timestamp, hikvision

I want to capture RTSP streams from different cameras (dahua, hikvision, etc.);
I am using the FFmpeg library, for each stream I need some real-time value.
The start_time_realtime member of AVFormatContext is exactly what I need.
This usually works and I can get the correct start time, but in some cases, start_time_realtime is AV_NOPTS_VALUE.
Do I need to set some correct settings for the camera in the web interface?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg sets `start_time_realtime` based on the NTP timestamp seen in the RTCP [Sender report](https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1889/19.htm) packet. If not received, `start_time_realtime` will remain uninitialized.